# "been often" vs "often been"

Tags: grammar, word-order, present-perfect, adverb-position

Which of these is the correct form:

> techniques have *been* **often** used for post-processing

or

> techniques have **often** *been* used for post-processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is natural. Adverbs of frequency "usually go before one-part verbs, after auxiliary verbs, and after *am/is was were*". (Swan, Practical English Usage,2005.24)

Comment: Thank you, especially for the reference. I was inclined to that, but found references to the first.

Comment: @psd "but found references to the first," shows both are acceptable.

Comment: @Kris, perhaps. Still, tunny's reply that the second is more "natural" makes sense to me. The "have been often" was in the paper and struck me as awkward. Furthermore, "have been often" references were more often than not from the Bible.

Comment: @Kris. I deliberately used 'more natural' rather than 'correct. This Ngram conforms that 'have often been' is far more commonly used than 'have been often': https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+have+been+often%2C+there+have+often+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20have%20been%20often%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20have%20often%20been%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Also @psd -- my point was that each has its merits and is used in appropriate context. 'Popular' is not grammatical but one may be needed more often than the other -- that doesn't mean anything.